# Which phrase should be used, in future or in the future?

Tags: word-choice

In the following sentence, which phrase should be used, in future or in the future.

> Please be punctual in future/in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The most idiomatic way is with the article, at least in North American English. That's how it's always said when talking about an event that's going to happen at a future time unless it's [**headlinese**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese) (the terse, abbreviated style of language used in news article titles, e.g. *Kaamatan festival to improve in future - Infra Development Minister*):

> Please be punctual **in the future**.
>
> Please try to be more considerate **in the future**.
>
> No one can say with absolute certainty what's going to happen **in the future**.

I don't think I've ever heard a person from North America use that other version without the article: *in future*. I can't say for sure, but it might be used in British English. Let's wait and see what a British person will say about this. Though, from my experience, I don't think there has ever been an occasion where I've heard a person even from Great Britain or Australia say *in future* in normal conversational English. My advice to you, stick with *in the future*. That's what most people say.

Comment: Interesting hearing from an AmE standpoint and "headlinese". As a British person we always (from what I have observed) would say "in future" referring to "from now on" unless you are referring to a specific point in time

Answer (score 2):

No difference whatsoever. AmE is fond of using *articles!* So, you find *the* in it! On the other hand, BrE would have it as *in future.*

> You use in future when saying what will happen from now on, which will be different from what has previously happened. The form **in the future** is sometimes used instead, *especially in American English.*

Reference to this is [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-the-future)

Another reference I found useful is [here on BTB.](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/favart/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_titls&page=9VorV7jvi51w.html) It says when you add the article the idea of *the action begins at this point of time* is absent! It also defines it in Canadian English. A good reference to go through.

Comment: Interesting - I wasn’t aware of this AmE/BrE distinction. I agree with your BTB link that *in future* is a synonym for *from now on* and that *in the future* has the sense of *one day (something will be true / will happen etc)*.

Comment: @Lawrence the best part of being an Indian is we use both Am/BrE...and get benefit of both the languages! I often tell my team that it should not happen in future! On the other hand, I tell to my daughter that "Just see, in the future, robots will take over humans!" :)

Comment: Haha, global village. Both examples in your comment are consistent with the BTB note above. You can add *the* to the *team* example or drop it from the other example - but if you do, the sense changes.

Answer (score -2):

If you say "in future" you need a noun to finish the sentence. for example:

> Please be punctual in future meetings

The reason for that, is because future (as in "in future") is an adjective, therefore needing a subject to describe. So that means that "in future" by itself is incorrect grammar.

> "In *the* future

would be correct because in this sentence "future" is a noun.

If you want to understand the difference between the adjective form, and the noun form of "future". [Here](https://www.google.com/search?ei=RX4PW5ueEuXujwTdjY7ADQ&q=future%20definition&oq=future%20d&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.35i39k1j0i20i263i264k1j0l8.508.784.0.2386.2.2.0.0.0.0.183.183.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.1.183....0.KTboiocvFbQ) is a link to the definition.

Comment: Incorrect! *I promise to do better in future;* there's no noun required!